# Accessing Journey Builder Entry Source and Entry Data - Object and Attributes

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I am trying to access Journey Builder Entry Source and Entry Data including objects and attributes for some analysis related to switching to a new Sales Cloud org which will then connect to SFMC.

There are a lot of journeys to review and I was wondering if there is a way to automate the process by exporting all running journey names including their entry sources, entry data, object and attributes that are included in the journeys. Ideally I also want to extract all personalisation that are used in the emails used in the journeys.

At the moment I can get list of all journey names by running 'Journey Builder Email Send Summary
Save' from the Analytics Builder.

I was looking at **Data View: Journey and Journey Activity** but I don't think this is possible from there. I was checking also the Data Extract Activity but I'm struggling to see if that's possible.

Example of the data I'm looking to extract:

Journey name; DE Name; Who; Object; Criteria (Entry); Related Objects criteria; Entry Data.

[image: Journey Data Example]

Answer (score 2):

You can get these information in journeys using Salesforce data entry source but I have to say it will be not an easy way.

First, you need to collect JourneyID from journeys. You can get it from `_Journey` data view. For example:

```
SELECT
JourneyID,
JourneyName,
VersionNumber,
JourneyStatus
FROM
_Journey
WHERE
JourneyStatus = 'Running'
```

And then you can make a loop with calling [the REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getInteractionCollection.html) each iteration to get the information based on the journeyID.

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
GET /interaction/v1/interactions?id={{YourJourneyID}}&extras=activities
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The response will have these attribute information

- **triggers.type**: **SalesforceObjectTriggerV2** (imply this journey using Salesforce data entry source)
- **triggers.configurationArguments.objectApiName**: Object
- **triggers.configurationArguments.whoToInject**: WHO
- **triggers.configurationArguments.relatedObjectFilterSummary**: Related Objects criteria
- **triggers.configurationArguments.primaryObjectFilterSummary**: journey criteria
- **triggers.configurationArguments.eventDataSummary**: Entry data

For the DE name, it's a bit tricky. You need to get it from the `eventDefinitionId`
**triggers.metaData.eventDefinitionId**

and then use [this API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getEventDefinitions.html) to get the eventDefinition information

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
GET /interaction/v1/eventDefinitions/{{YourEventDefinitionID}}
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

In the response of this 2nd REST API call, you will get the **dataExtensionName** attribute for the DE name.

**Updated 25-01-23**: Update details for API part

Comment: When making a loop with calling the REST APIs do I need to do it for each individual journey or I can do it for all of them? I'm not very familiar with this type of calls so apologies if I sounds silly but where all this information be stored? Thank you

Comment: @NikolayNikolov yes, you need to do the REST API call for each individual journey (ID) to get the information. For storing the information, it's another story. The response of the API call will give you the values and from there you will need to do an additional step to write a function to add these information into a DE where you can extract it later

Comment: Thank you, I ran it once and it's working. Do you have an example of how this can be displayed in DE?

Comment: @NikolayNikolov I assume you have all the information you need from the response, now you will need to store it in an array and add it into the DE (you already created before). You can refer to this function https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsAdd.html

Comment: do you know a way to pull information of all personalisation used in the journey emails for example any attributes used in AMPscript? I'm trying to understand what will get affected after we switch to new Sales Cloud and reconnect to MC. Thank you

Comment: @NikolayNikolov  I'm not aware of it, but it seems complicated to achieve this. If you switch to new SalesCloud instance, most likely it will ruin the journeys which involves using the Marketing Cloud Connector